# Adding definitions for strongly typed events

Tags: typescript, events

I'm trying to figure out how to efficiently add strongly typed events to my project, but keep running into odd issues. Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
declare class EventEmitter<T> {
    on<K extends keyof T>(event: K, fn: (...args: T[K]) => void, context?: any): void;
    once<K extends keyof T>(event: K, fn: (...args: T[K]) => void, context?: any): void;
    emit<K extends keyof T>(event: K, ...args: T[K]): boolean;
}

interface MyEvents {
    'eventA': [string, number];
    'eventB': [string, { prop: string, prop2: number }, (arg: string) => void];
}

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter<MyEvents> {
    // ...
}

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

myEmitter.on('eventA', (str, num) => {});
myEmitter.once('eventB', (str, obj, fn) => {});

myEmitter.emit('eventA', 'foo', 3);
```

The first issue is that apparently tuples aren't valid types for rest parameters, despite simply being arrays of typed elements under the hood (I believe this is currently being worked on). I suppose that's fine if I forgo typing the `emit` method, and just make my events map to function types instead of tuples. This would also give the benefit of a little extra information about what the arguments are.

```
declare class EventEmitter<T> {
    on<K extends keyof T>(event: K, fn: T[K], context?: any): void;
    once<K extends keyof T>(event: K, fn: T[K], context?: any): void;
}

interface MyEvents {
    'eventA': (str: string, num: number) => void;
    'eventB': (
        str: string,
        data: { prop: string, prop2: number }, 
        fn: (arg: string) => void
    ) => void;
}

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter<MyEvents> {
    // ...
}

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

myEmitter.on('eventA', (str, num) => {});
myEmitter.once('eventB', (str, obj, fn) => {});
```

At this point I'm stumped. IntelliSense can infer the proper signatures for `on` or `once`, but the actual arguments types are only inferred for the event with the most arguments on its callback, which makes *no* sense to me. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17391) a few days ago, but have yet to get a response. I'm unsure if this is actually a bug, or if I'm overlooking something.

In the meantime, are there any efficient ways of doing this? I've thought about just adding overloads to my emitter class like this (here `EventEmitter` is just using the node typings):

```
class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
    on(event: 'eventA', fn: (str: string, num: number) => void);
    on(event: 'eventB', fn: (
        str: string,
        data: { prop: string, prop2: number },
        fn: (arg: string) => void
    ) => void);
}
```

However this requires me to have an actual implementation of `on` in my class, and if I want types for `once` or `emit` I have to duplicate all of my event definitions. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I [commented](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17391#issuecomment-320052809) on your reported issue; it does seem buggy.  Obviously you could work around it by annotating the types on your function parameters.  It's annoying but it works:

```
myEmitter.on('eventA', (str: string, num: number) => {}); // no errors
myEmitter.on('eventA', (str: string) => {}); // no error, [see FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)
myEmitter.on('eventA', (str: number) => {}); // error as expected
myEmitter.on('eventA', (str: string, num: number, boo: boolean) => {}); // error as expected
```

---

You're right that you can't use tuple types as rest parameters.  You can *kind of* work around that by converting the tuple to an array, but now it forgets the order:

```
type AsArray<T extends any[]> = (T[number])[]

declare class EventEmitter<T extends {[K in keyof T]: any[]}> {
  on<K extends keyof T>(event: K, fn: (...args: AsArray<T[K]>) => void, context?: any): void;
  once<K extends keyof T>(event: K, fn: (...args: AsArray<T[K]>) => void, context?: any): void;
  emit<K extends keyof T>(event: K, ...args: AsArray<T[K]>): boolean;
}

myEmitter.emit('eventA', 2, 1); // oops, rest args are string|number
```

You can get closer by figuring out a reasonable maximum number of function parameters (say 4) and declaring them this way:

```
type TupleFunctionParams<T extends any[], R=void> = {
    (a0: T[0], a1: T[1], a2: T[2], a3: T[3], a4: T[4], ...a5Plus: AsArray<T>): R
  }

declare class EventEmitter<T extends {[K in keyof T]: any[]}> {
  on<K extends keyof T>(event: K, fn: TupleFunctionParams<T[K]>, context?: any): void;
  once<K extends keyof T>(event: K, fn: TupleFunctionParams<T[K]>, context?: any): void;
  emit<K extends keyof T>(event: K, a0?: T[K][0], a1?: T[K][1], a2?: T[K][2], a3?: T[K][3], a4?: T[K][4], ...args: AsArray<T[K]>): boolean;
}
```

The arguments you specify in your tuple will now appear in the right order.  However, you can still leave out arguments ([see FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)) and you can still specify *extra* arguments which will be unions of the types in your tuple:

```
myEmitter.emit('eventA', 1, 2); // error as expected
myEmitter.emit('eventA', 'one', 2); // works
myEmitter.emit('eventA', 'one'); // also works, all args are optional
myEmitter.emit('eventA', 'one', 2, 3) // ALSO works, because subsequent args are union
myEmitter.on('eventA', (str, num) => { }); // works
myEmitter.on('eventA', (str) => { }); // as above
myEmitter.on('eventA', (str, num, rando) => { }); // as above, rando is string | number
```

The best I can do after that is to append a bunch of `never` to your tuples:

```
interface MyEvents {
  'eventA': [string, number, never, never, never, never, never];
  'eventB': [string, { prop: string, prop2: number }, (arg: string) => void, never, never, never, never];
}
```

Now at least extra parameters will tend to be typed somewhat usefully:

```
myEmitter.emit('eventA', 'one', 2, 3) // Error on 3, should be undefined
myEmitter.on('eventA', (str, num, rando) => { }); // now rando is never
```

---

[See it on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=type%20AsArray%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%28T%5Bnumber%5D%29%5B%5D%0D%0Atype%20TupleFunctionParams%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%2C%20R%3Dvoid%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%28a0%3A%20T%5B0%5D%2C%20a1%3A%20T%5B1%5D%2C%20a2%3A%20T%5B2%5D%2C%20a3%3A%20T%5B3%5D%2C%20a4%3A%20T%5B4%5D%2C%20...a5Plus%3A%20AsArray%3CT%3E%29%3A%20R%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20EventEmitter%3CT%20extends%20%7B%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20any%5B%5D%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20on%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%28event%3A%20K%2C%20fn%3A%20TupleFunctionParams%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%2C%20context%3F%3A%20any%29%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20once%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%28event%3A%20K%2C%20fn%3A%20TupleFunctionParams%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%2C%20context%3F%3A%20any%29%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20emit%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%28event%3A%20K%2C%20a0%3F%3A%20T%5BK%5D%5B0%5D%2C%20a1%3F%3A%20T%5BK%5D%5B1%5D%2C%20a2%3F%3A%20T%5BK%5D%5B2%5D%2C%20a3%3F%3A%20T%5BK%5D%5B3%5D%2C%20a4%3F%3A%20T%5BK%5D%5B4%5D%2C%20...args%3A%20AsArray%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%29%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyEvents%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%27eventA%27%3A%20%5Bstring%2C%20number%2C%20never%2C%20never%2C%20never%2C%20never%2C%20never%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%27eventB%27%3A%20%5Bstring%2C%20%7B%20prop%3A%20string%2C%20prop2%3A%20number%20%7D%2C%20%28arg%3A%20string%29%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%20never%2C%20never%2C%20never%2C%20never%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyEmitter%20extends%20EventEmitter%3CMyEvents%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20myEmitter%20%3D%20new%20MyEmitter%28%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AmyEmitter.emit%28%27eventA%27%2C%201%2C%202%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%20as%20expected%0D%0AmyEmitter.emit%28%27eventA%27%2C%20%27one%27%2C%202%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20works%0D%0AmyEmitter.emit%28%27eventA%27%2C%20%27one%27%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20also%20works%2C%20all%20args%20are%20optional%0D%0AmyEmitter.emit%28%27eventA%27%2C%20%27one%27%2C%202%2C%203%29%20%2F%2F%20error%0D%0AmyEmitter.on%28%27eventA%27%2C%20%28str%2C%20num%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20works%0D%0AmyEmitter.on%28%27eventA%27%2C%20%28str%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20as%20above%0D%0AmyEmitter.on%28%27eventA%27%2C%20%28str%2C%20num%2C%20rando%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20rando%20is%20never)

Okay, that's the best I can do.  Hope it helps.  Good luck!